# Android Out of Memory Error

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

In my Activity, i'm trying to do a bit of image processing of my own. I have algorithms that manipulate the image the way I want to, which is the object LabAware. I have noticed that when I comment out the last 3 lines of codes, i don't get a Out of Memory Error. Also, I pass an Bitmap in my algorithm, where I do image processing and accessing of pixels. I also added the android:largeHeap = "true; statement in my manifest file. How do I tackle the Out of Memory Error?

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
Bitmap imageTwo = image.createBitmap(900,1200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
grayImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image,900,1200,false);
//grayImage is a public member variable of the activity

LabAware  lab = new LabAware();
lab.calculateChip(grayImage,852 ,420);
printInt(lab.green1);
```

Comment: Please share logcat if you are facing any errors

Comment: You are creating way too many bitmap objects. If you don't need the `Drawable` reference try importing `Bitmap` directly. Also remove the imageTwo reference and just call `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 900, 1200, false);`. And lastly once you are done with your bitmap call `bitmap.recycle()` on it.

Comment: `I have noticed that when I comment out the last 3 lines of codes, i don't get a Out of Memory Error.` You just answered your own question, the library/code you are using is implemented badly otherwise you haven't fully read the code docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `android:largeHeap="true"`.  If that only delays the crash, you probably have a memory leak.  The allocation that triggers the crash usually has nothing to do with the problem, so the stack trace will be useless.  You need to [dump the heap](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html) and look for objects that shouldn't be there.  Find out what's holding a reference to them, then study your code to find out why.